# Nested prefixes accross loggers in Python

Tags: python, logging

I'm currently working on a project where were use a single root logger. I understand from reading about logging that is a Bad Thing but am struggling to find a nice solution to a nice benefit this gives us.

Something we do (in part, to get around not having different loggers but in part gives us a nice feature) is to have a `log_prefix` decorator.

e.g.

```
@log_prefix("Download")
def download_file():
    logging.info("Downloading file..")
    connection = get_connection("127.0.0.1")
    //Do other stuff
    return file

@log_prefix("GetConnection")
def get_connection(url):
    logging.info("Making connection")
    //Do other stuff
    logging.info("Finished making connection")
    return connection
```

This gives us some nicely formatting logs that might look like:

```
Download:Downloading file..
Download:GetConnection:Making Connection
Download:GetConnection:Other stuff
Download:GetConnection:Finished making connection
Download:Other stuff
```

This also means that if we have

```
@log_prefix("StartTelnetSession")
logging.info("Starting telnet session..")
connection = get_connection("127.0.0.1")
```

We get the same prefix at the end:

```
StartTelnetSession:Starting telnet session..
StartTelnetSession:GetConnection:Making Connection
StartTelnetSession:GetConnection:Other stuff
StartTelnetSession:GetConnection:Finished making connection
```

This has proven to be quite useful for development and support.

I can see plenty of cases where actually just using a separate logger for the action would solve our problem but I can also see cases where throwing away the nesting we have will make things worse.

Are there any patterns or common uses out there for nesting loggers? i.e

```
logging.getLogger("Download").getLogger("MakingConnection")
```

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

Logger names are hierarchical.

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Download.MakingConnection")
```

This logger would inherit any configuration from `logging.getLogger("Download")`.

Python 2.7 also added a convenience function for accessing descendants of an arbitrary logger.

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Download.MakingConnection")

parent_logger = logging.getLogger("Download")
child_logger = parent_logger.getChild("MakingConnection")

assert logger is child_logger
```

Comment: I did not know that! But I don't see a way around having to add the Parent logger name as an argument to my @log_prefix decorator (which we currently don't have to care about because there's only 1 logger)

Comment: What does the decorator do? From what I can see, you would just have a global logger, something like `download_logger = logging.getLogger("Download")`, then in each of the two functions you would simply call `logger = download_logger.getChild("<name>")` to get a more-specifc logger.

Comment: The decorator will push a prefix on to the global logger which is then popped when the decorated function finishes execution. This way if get_connection() was called by either download_file() or open_telnet_session() we would have the same prefix added. (So what I said in my previous comment is wrong - get_connection() would need to take a parent_logger parameter)

Comment: Oh, so your logger name is determined dynamically using the call stack, not statically by some pre-determined log hierarchy. I don't think there's anything else you can do, other than what you are doing.

Comment: No, we only have 1 logger. And it's our own subclass which has a `add_prefix` and `remove_prefix`. Which @log_prefix is calling. The point is that because we only have 1 logger @log_prefix can just get that (`getLogger()`) and add/remove at will. I suppose there isn't really a way around this.

Comment: `[ x[2] for x in traceback.extract_stack() ]` might be useful; it creates a list of all the function names on the current call stack. You could use this inside your decorator, rather than maintaining your own stack as the decorator is called.

Comment: I had thought about that but the problem here is that we don't necessarily want every function to stick a prefix on, just ones we decide

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [LoggerAdapter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#loggeradapter-objects) to add extra contextual information:

utils_logging.py:

```
import functools

def log_prefix(logger, label, prefix=list()):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            prefix.append(label)
            logger.extra['prefix'] = ':'.join(prefix)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            prefix.pop()
            logger.extra['prefix'] = ':'.join(prefix)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

foo.py:

```
import logging
import utils_logging as UL
import bar

logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), {'prefix':''})
@UL.log_prefix(logger, "Download")
def download_file():
    logger.info("Downloading file..")
    connection = bar.get_connection("127.0.0.1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(prefix)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    download_file()
    bar.get_connection('foo')
```

bar.py:

```
import logging
import utils_logging as UL
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger(__name__), {'prefix':''})

@UL.log_prefix(logger, "GetConnection")
def get_connection(url):
    logger.info("Making connection")
    logger.info("Finished making connection")
```

yields

```
Download __main__ INFO Downloading file..
Download:GetConnection bar INFO Making connection
Download:GetConnection bar INFO Finished making connection
GetConnection bar INFO Making connection
GetConnection bar INFO Finished making connection
```

Note: I don't think it is a good idea to have a new Logger instance for each
prefix because [these instances are not garbage
collected](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output). All
you need is for some `prefix` variable to take on a different value depending on
context. You don't need a new Logger instance for that -- one LoggerAdapter will
do.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this example only work if log_prefix is defined in the same module and after the logger definition?

Comment: I've also experimented with passing logger in to the @log_prefix decorator but if I have get_connection() defined in another module than this won't work either

Comment: I've modified the code to show how you could put `log_prefix` (and the functions) in different modules.

Comment: Thanks, I think we also need an extra update of 'prefix' `logger.extra['prefix'] = ':'.join(prefix) ` after the pop

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to keep hunting for a solution. This is nice and gets us close but as soon as I use a un-prefixed logger I get a key error on 'prefix'.

Comment: Yes, this solution requires that you pass a LoggerAdapter to the `log_prefix` decorator.

Comment: No, that would be fine. It requires that my logger has a .extra['prefix'] attribute because of the %(prefix)s format string

Comment: Oh, I see. I've edited the code above to initialize the LoggerAdapter dict to include a `prefix` key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative which uses a [logging.Filter](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) to modify the `record.msg`. By modifying the message instead of adding an `%(prefix)s` field, 
the format does not need to change.

This will make it easier to mix loggers which make use of `log_prefix` and those that don't.

To get the prefix, the logger should be initialized with a call to `add_prefix_filter`:

```
logger = UL.add_prefix_filter(logging.getLogger(__name__))
```

To append labels to the prefix, the functions should be decorated with `@log_prefix(label)`, as before.

---

utils_logging.py:

```
import functools
import logging

prefix = list()

def log_prefix(label):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            prefix.append(label)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                prefix.pop()
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class PrefixFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if prefix:
            record.msg = '{}:{}'.format(':'.join(prefix), record.msg)
        return True

def add_prefix_filter(logger):
    logger.addFilter(PrefixFilter())
    return logger
```

main.py:

```
import logging
import bar
import utils_logging as UL

logger = UL.add_prefix_filter(logging.getLogger(__name__))

@UL.log_prefix("Download")
def download_file():
    logger.info("Downloading file..")
    connection = bar.get_connection("127.0.0.1")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format='%(message)s')

    logger.info('Starting...')
    download_file()
    bar.get_connection('foo')
```

bar.py:

```
import logging
import utils_logging as UL

logger = UL.add_prefix_filter(logging.getLogger(__name__))

@UL.log_prefix("GetConnection")
def get_connection(url):
    logger.info("Making connection")
    logger.info("Finished making connection")
```

yields

```
Starting...
Download:Downloading file..
Download:GetConnection:Making connection
Download:GetConnection:Finished making connection
GetConnection:Making connection
GetConnection:Finished making connection
```